# Disable MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR when developing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to disable the MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR setting for Chrome storage during development? I'm completely blocked right now because I hit the max while testing a new feature. It's really frustrating.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`chrome.storage.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#property-local) instead of [`chrome.storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#property-sync) during development.

Synchronized storage is rate-limited, because everything is sent to Google's servers. Local Chrome storage (not to be confused with `localStorage`) is only saved to the user's local file system and not throttled.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm actually testing the sync functionality, so that's not an option. :-(

Comment: @WarrenBenedetto Try logging in with another Google account. If that doesn't work, try to create a completely new user data directory, e.g. using `chromium --user-data-dir=/tmp/whatever`.